# How to combine JavaScript - PHP - PowerShell

Tags: javascript, php, powershell

So I have my main.php page on which you have a button:

```
<button onclick="Raport()" type="button">Raport</button>
```

It calls a JavaScript function:

```
<script>
   function Raport() {
   const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onload = function() {
      document.getElementById("Raport").innerHTML = this.responseText;
   }
   xhttp.open("GET", "Raport.php");
   xhttp.send();
</script>
```

raport.php called by javascript run powershell script:

```
<?php Shell_Exec('powershell -InputFormat none -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoProfile -Command "& { . \"..\Scripts\export.ps1\"; }"'); ?>
```

Which create csv file on server.

Now my goal is to download that file when Raport() function end. I was able to allow user to download that file by:

```
fetch("http://host/scripts/raport.csv")
.then((res) => { return res.blob(); })
.then((data) => {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
  a.download = "Raport.csv";
  a.click();
```

But it will not wait until Raport() function end. Then I tried adding after xhttp.send():

```
.done(Raport() {
    (fetch from above)
})
.fail(Raport() {
    // Tell the user something bad happened
});
```

But it end up not working.

Any advice how should I aproach this problem and if my approach is correct one.

Comment: Where did you put the `fetch`? And why do you use both fetch and XHMLHttpRequest?

Comment: 1) don't mix XHR and fetch, it makes your code inconsistent! fetch is the modern version, so maybe stick to that. 2) "it won't wait"...well that depends where you run it. If you put it in the callback which runs when the call to Raport.php has completed, then it will obviously wait.

Comment: P.S. Did you mean "report" instead of "raport", perhaps?

Comment: I would try to just use one fetch, and on the php side, exec the file generator first, then use some kind of fpassthru to send something to the browser, then use the blob in the browser

Comment: That's true, once the powershell is finished, the file should be available, so PHP could return the file data directly back in the same request.